# PHP session action

Tags: php

I have problem with understanding what is wrong with my code. I try to learn sessions in php and I want to pass value from button. My code is:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sessions</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="test2.php">
    <button name="mybtn" value="1">Button 1</button>
    <button name="mybtn" value="2">Button 2</button>
    <button name="mybtn" value="3">Button 3</button>
    <?php $_SESSION['SavedValue']=$_POST['mybtn'] ?>
</form>

<?php print_r($_POST) ?>
<br>
<?php print_r($_SESSION) ?>

</body>
</html>
```

and

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sessions</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php print_r($_POST) ?>
<br>
<?php print_r($_SESSION); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

When i delete action and just push for example button 2 it shows in $_POST Array ([mybtn]=>1) and same value for SavedValue. But when i use action to open in test2.php it shows correct value in $_POST array but don't update in $_SESSION. Can someone explain why $_SESSION array don't update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the bottom code is test2.php, when you click the button the data is POSTed there, but you have no reference to it in that code. You need to set the `$_SESSION` variable in the script receiving the POST data not the one generating it.

This line from your top script needs to be in your bottom script (after the session start line):

```
$_SESSION['SavedValue']=$_POST['mybtn']
```

Answer (score 0):

when you submit test1.php the form values are passed to test2.php now if you want to store the value in session you have to update session value in test2.php not in test. below is the example code:

test1.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sessions</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="test2.php">
    <button name="mybtn" value="1">Button 1</button>
    <button name="mybtn" value="2">Button 2</button>
    <button name="mybtn" value="3">Button 3</button>

</form>

<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
<br>
<?php print_r($_SESSION); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

test2.php

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php $_SESSION['SavedValue']=$_POST['mybtn']; ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sessions</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php print_r($_POST) ?>
<br>
<?php print_r($_SESSION); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope this answer may help you. :)